# How can I Group Data in WPF Toolkid Datagrid That is Bound to a Datatable

Tags: wpf, datatable, wpftoolkit

I'm a newer to wpf. I'm developing a small application using wpf in .net 3.5. I have a wpf toolkid datagrid control that is bound with a datatable. Now I'm unable to group data on my datagrid.

who can tell me how can i accomplish this?

Here is my xmal

```
        <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True"
                                  Background="White"
                                  Foreground="Black">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AdmissionDate}"/>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Window.Resources>

<tk:DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="5,0,5,0"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                     Name="testTakerGrid" 
                     AlternationCount="2" 
                     AlternatingRowBackground="Azure"
                     RowHeaderWidth="40"
                     CanUserSortColumns="True"
                     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                     GridLinesVisibility="None"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                     SelectionMode="Single"
                     CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
         <tk:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <tk:DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.Panel>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </tk:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
<tk:DataGrid.Columns>                
        <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Serial Id" Binding="{Binding Path=SerialId, Mode=OneWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="60"/>              
        <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Width="200"/>
        <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Path=Gender, Mode=OneWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
        <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Admission Date" Binding="{Binding Path=AdmissionDate, Mode=OneWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, StringFormat='d'}" Width="100" />
</tk:DataGrid.Columns>
</tk:DataGrid>
```

Here is my code behide

```
    public partial class MainApp : Window
    {
        TestTakerDataSet takerDs = new TestTakerDataSet();
        TestTakersTableAdapter takerTa = new TestTakersTableAdapter();

        CollectionView view;
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                 takerTa.FillByTerm(takerDs.TestTakers, "2010-2011T1E");        

                        view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(takerDs.TestTakers);
this.DataContext=view;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sovantha In your code given above i am not able to see anywhere the datagrid binding.. Either use Resource binding in XAML or bind the Datagrid ItemSource in Code behind as below:

```
testTakerGrid.ItemSource = view;
```

Comment: I have set datagrid's ItemsSource="{Binding}" and in my code behide i have this.DataContext = takerDs.TestTakers; the grid display data as expected.

Comment: Try binding the DataContext with the view as grouping is enabled in CollectionView.

Comment: I changed my code to : this.DataContext=view; The grid display as normal but no grouping appears.

Comment: You need to apply grouping in your code file on the CollectionView.
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("AdmissionDate"));

Fora a better understanding please visit the below site, it explains exactly what you want to achieve.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126.aspx

Comment: when you specify the Group style for the datagrid, it is the style for the Header of that group. For example in the link mentioned above, Group header is defined in the Expander.